# Delphi - Passing data from a TQuery to Quickreport component (QRDBText)

Tags: delphi, quickreports

This may be a newbie question, but I was unable to solve this problem.

I have a TQuery component (Query1) wich returns me a dataset from a database.

I would like to pass the records in it to a QuickReport QRDBText component - with no success so far.

I am creating the Query1 in run-time, and then an event (button press) would come up with the Quickreport. I got this far with it:

```
QReport.DataSet:=Query1;
QRDBText1.DataSet:=Query1;
QRDBText1.Datafield:='Vnev';    //first field in query
QRDBText2.DataSet:=Query1;
QRDBText2.Datafield:='Knev';    //second field in query
QRDBText3.DataSet:=Query1;
QRDBText3.Datafield:='Idcard';  //third field in query
```

But this shows me the big grey nothing.
If I operate with a sample database and place a TTable on the QuickReport, and set up the connections via the Object Inspector, it works. But again: I need to display data from my Query.
Any help would come handy! Thanks

Comment: In which kind of band is the QRDBTExt1?

Comment: It is in Detail type. This should repeat itself until the end of the data stream.

Comment: Show more code. Are you Opening the Query? Did you try doing a test "while not Query1.Eof do Next" on the Query to make sure it's actually returning some data?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Of course, I opened the query before gathering any data out of it. But I didn't use the Next function of it, because it was not needed when the source was the sample database.

Comment: I made some progress. Now the QuickReport returns me the data from the query, but only the first row. I tought that if I put the necessary data fileds in the Detail band of the report, it will repeat itself until the data stream ends. How could I get it working? (to make it repeat)

Answer (score 0):

The `QRdetailband` should set to true and fill the `QRdbtext` on it.